# Поиск двойников

Tags: python, python-3.x

На входе дается буква first_letter и два списка с именами.

Необходимо создать и распечатать третий список, в котором каждым элементом будет имя, начинающееся с буквы first_letter и при этом содержится в обеих указанных выше списках. Порядок слов в результирующем списке должно быть таким же, как и в первом.

Пример входных данных:

```
J

Justin Sam Jane Paul Fred

Jane Richard Carl Justin
```

Результат:

```
['Justin', 'Jane']
```

Я немного запутался, как выполнить эту задачу

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
first_letter = input()

first_list = input().rstrip().split()

second_list = input().rstrip().split()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_letter = input()
first_list = "Justin Sam Jane Paul Fred".split(" ")
second_list = "Jane Richard Carl Justin".split(" ")

output_list = []

for item in first_list:
    if item[0] == first_letter:
        if item in second_list and not item in output_list:
            output_list.append(item)

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> first_list = "Justin Sam Jane Paul Fred".split()
>>> second_list = "Jane Richard Carl Justin".split()
>>> [x for x in first_list if x.startswith(first_letter) and x in second_list]
['Justin', 'Jane']
```

Если имя начинается с first_letter и есть во втором списке.

Comment: не совсем нужно сравнить 2 списка и вывести имена которые есть сразу в 2 списках